# Interpolation of missing time series sensor data based on another sensor pattern

Tags: r, interpolation

I have two sensors in the same place, but one of the sensors stopped working, and I therefore want to interpolate the missing values based on the pattern that exists in the other sensor that still works.

The Y axis is a value is degrees in celsius, and the X is aggregated data on 10 minute interval.

Picture of the graph and data I want to interpolate.

[image]

I am unsure how to do this, and which package and formula to use. Any ideas?

Comment: you can impute the missing values by package:mice, missforest rather than imputing by mean/median

Comment: @Prahlad I've looked into missforest, but I am very unsure how to do this. Any suggestions?